# Cordova serve not running in ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, ionic3

cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):

Static file server running on: http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 0):

Try removing platform and adding it again.